# Data not showing in iphone tableView

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I am getting data from json. It is working OK but the problem is that data is not showing in tableView.

I have checked the values that I assign to cell using NSLog but cell is not displaying any data.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1; 
}

// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    int count = [surveyList count];
    NSLog(@"These are rows %d",count);
    return [surveyList count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    ObjectData *data = [surveyList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
    NSString *testingClient = data.survey_title;
    NSLog(testingClient);
    NSString *cellText = testingClient;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Make sure you assign delegate to your table view,

Comment: yes i have assigned delagate someone told that tableviewrealod data is creating problem like but i have not reloaded any thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you not missing this?

```
[[cell textLabel] setText:testingClient];
```

You aren't assigning any text to the cell without it.

Answer (score 1):

You should assign that text to label of cell.

```
cell.textLabel.text = testingClient;
```

Comment: first try loading some dummy data into your table.. make sure  your table is getting populated and is working fine. find a tutorial for making a tableView